# C++ - QT - SIGNAL and SLOT understanding

Tags: c++, qt

I dont understand why this code doesnt work, maybe I haven't understanding the concept of SIGNAL and SLOT.

For example: I have a class named `MainWindow`, this class contains the ui components. On this UI I can start and shut down a local server. This server is defined in class `MyServer`. The `MainWindow` class has a reference to `MyServer class '&myServer'`. If i do this in class `mainwindow.cpp` it works:

```
connect(ui->startServer,SIGNAL(clicked()),&myServer,SLOT(startServer()));
connect(ui->shutdownServer,SIGNAL(clicked()),&myServer,SLOT(shutDownServer()));
```

but this line not:

```
connect(&myServer,SIGNAL(signalMessage()), this, SLOT(slotUpdate()));
```

This Problem is: I have a SIGNAL named `void signalMessage();`in MyServer class, this signal is called in function `void startServer();` and `void shutDownServer()`

```
signals:
    void signalMessage();
```

Normally after calling `singalMessage()` in `MyServer` class, the function `slotUpdate()` in `MainWindow` class should be called. But only `signalMessage()` is called and not `slotUpadate()`.

I hope anyone understand my problem. I can define slot and signal from MainWindow to MyServer but not reverse. :(

**Edit:** Okey, here some code for understanding my problem:

mainwindow.h

```
...
public:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    MyServer myServer;


public slots:
    void slotUpdate();
...
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
...
connect(ui->startServer,SIGNAL(clicked()),&myServer,SLOT(startServer()));
connect(ui->shutdownServer,SIGNAL(clicked()),&myServer,SLOT(shutDownServer()));
connect(&myServer,SIGNAL(signalMessage()), this, SLOT(slotUpdate()));
...
void MainWindow::slotUpdate()
{
    qDebug()<< "update()";
}
...
```

myserver.h

```
public slots:
void startServer();//start the server on 127.0.0.1 port: 1234
void shutDownServer();//disconnect threads, shut down server

signals:
    void signalMessage();
```

myserver.cpp

```
...
void MyServer::startServer(){
if(!this->listen(QHostAddress::Any,1234)){
    message.append("Could not start server, because server is already running");
}else{
    message.append("Listening...");
}

emit signalMessage();
}

...
void MyServer::signalMessage()
{
  qDebug() << "getMessage()";
}
```

Comment: with `the signal is called`, you mean that you `emit` it, right?

Comment: yes, i wrote "emit signalMessage();"

Comment: Can you show some more code with the relevant parts (especially slot and signal definitions) from your `.h` file? When you launch a debug build of your application from the command line, do you get any output like `No such slot`?

Comment: this is most likely a connect issue - could you debug the `connect(&myServer,SIGNAL(signalMessage()), this, SLOT(slotUpdate())); ` (it returns boolean ) and see what the result is?

Comment: I have a similar issue, where my GUI object receives signals from a foreign thread, but those outcoming are lost. When I use a QThread instead, it's all right... Do you run MyServer in a separate thread ?

Comment: i have set a breakpoint on line but this is the output "&"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Inappropriate ioctl for device\n";"

Comment: @ CapelliC: MyServer isnt running on a thread, do you mean, that's the solution?

Comment: I don't understand sufficiently your problem, then don't take my comment as a hint. I was just reporting ( and ranting ) about my problem: I also can't understand, and - albeit I hate this - I worked around (or better, messed it) with custom events. Now it start to work...

Comment: i will wrote in my MainWindow class, if anyone call the signal "signalMessage()" where is defined in class MyServer than call the function "slotUpdate()" in ManWindow

Comment: Have you set the Q_OBJECT macro on your MainWindow class?

Comment: @Alex That class stub is probably generated, so the Q_OBJECT macro is definitely set in that class, but it might not be in the class MyServer.

Answer (score 2):

In order to receive/emit signals:

1. Your class must be derived from QObject.
2. Your class must contain Q_OBJECT macro within its declaration.
3. Header file with this class must be processed with moc (happens automatically, when you use qmake to generate project file).

Troubleshooting:

1. If your header didn't originally have classes with signal/slots and you added them, you'll need to re-run qmake and regenerate Makefile(or visual studio project file).
2. Build debug versions of your program as console applications (`CONFIG += console` in *.pro file) OR read debug output when you run your program. If you make a typo and qt can't connect to a signal it will print message about this problem either into debug output window or into stdout/stderr. That's the only way to notice that you failed to establish connection - connections are established when you RUN application (at runtime), not at compile-time.
3. If you forget to add Q_OBJECT into class declaration or if you didn't run your headers (with classes that have signals/slot) through moc, you won't be able to connect to signals/slots.

There should be no need to write function body for signals. If you had to write function body, there's a problem with your code.

Also:
**Qt has great documentation, so you should read it**
If you installed qt, documentation should be available via "assistant" program, and it is also [available online](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/).

Answer (score 1):

If you have to define the `signalMessage` function, it means that you didn't use the `Q_OBJECT` macro in the `MyServer` class definition.

Answer (score 1):

The Solution:

@arne:

"You provided an implementation for the function in the source file, i.e. void MyServer::signalMessage() { qDebug() << "getMessage()"; }. That is not correct."

"The connection statement was correct already. The fact that your sever receives the other signal indicates that the QOBJECT macro is there. Just remove the function implementation, i.e. the code I quoted in my previous comment (from the cpp file)"

So I must delete the implementation of `singalMessage();` in .cpp file. After this the line
connect(&myServer, SIGNAL(singalMessage()), this, SLOT(slotUpdate())); works.

Answer (score 0):

You must not implement `signalMessage` yourself, as you have done in your `myserver.cpp` file. This way, the one from `QObject` will be overridden and not signal is sent out.

Comment: whats do you mean with "implement ... yourself, as you have done in your myserver.cpp file" ?

Comment: You provided an implementation for the function in the source file, i.e. ``void MyServer::signalMessage()
{
  qDebug() << "getMessage()";
}``. That is not correct.

Comment: @user1895683 The body of the signals are defined by the moc (the meta object compiler), so if you declare the function in the signals section, and you add the Q_OBJECT in the class definition, you shouldn't be able to define them yourself. You would have a "multiple definition" error at the linking stage.

Comment: Okey, how can i write a connection from MyServer to MainWindow?

Comment: The connection statement was correct already. The fact that your sever receives the other signal indicates that the `QOBJECT` macro is there. Just remove the function implementation, i.e. the code I quoted in my previous comment (from the cpp file)

Comment: but i need this function, because startServer() is a slot, and can not be a signal :(

Comment: Erm, what? I don't understand what the problem is with that. What does `startServer` have to do with `signalMessage`, apart from the `emit signalMessage();` statement? Have you even tried my suggestion? If yes, please post the error message.